# Remove margin for the div for which width is given in percentage

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

In styled components of React JS, I have given the width for div in percentage to make it responsive....
But the div is getting margin at right which is making the alignment disturbed.
How to get rid of this margin.
[image: This is the image]

```
export const BannerHeaderText = styled.h1`
    width: 46.5%;
    height: 64px; 
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.14;
    `
export const BannerParagraph = styled.p`
    width: 51.4%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.38;
    `
```

I am getting the width as I needed.

```
<BannerParagraphBlock>

                <BannerHeaderText>
                    Solveing the most common problems in marketing
                </BannerHeaderText>

                <BannerParagraph>
                    Exquisite codially mr happiness of neglected distrusts.
                    Boisterous impossible unaffected he me everything.
                </BannerParagraph>

                <SeeAllProductsButton>{message.SayEffectHomePageSeeAllProductsButton.value}</SeeAllProductsButton>

            </BannerParagraphBlock>
```

**Missed Data**

BannerHeaderText is h1 and BannerParagrap is p
BannerParagraphBlock is section

Comment: Have you tried to use `display: inline-block` on `BannerHeaderText ` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your CSS code **reset** your margins for the `<div>` tag. Then later you can give the margins as required. This is how it looks like,

```
    div{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
```

Hopefully this will work!

Comment: Sorry those are h1 and p tags and I have made margin and padding to zero earlier but no use

Answer (score 0):

HTML headings are **block-level** elements.
From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

> A block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container), thereby creating a "block."

In your case you can do this to make the heading center-aligned

```
h1.heading {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

You can see in the code-snippet below that the heading (in red border) is center-aligned.

```css
h1.heading {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 352px;
}

p {
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Solving the most common problems in marketting</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
```

Comment: It is occupying the whole section but the width should be as expected like 352px it is occupying 757px

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex` to get the same

below i posted an example

more update of `flex` **[FLEX](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 19px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 352px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  max-width: 352px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper button {
  background: #7C6ECC;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, rem, neque rerum nemo nam dolor ea nihil
  </p>
  <button>
    See all products
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As we all know. h1 is a block-level element, so it will occupy the space of the nearest block-level ancestor. For block-level element, the horizontal direction satisfy the below equation:

```
'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block
```

The default margin、 padding is 0, and border-style is none, so border width is also 0. Thus, when you apply a specific width to h1, the equation may not satisfy.
This situation is called "over-constrained" when `margin-right` is ignored and is calculated so as to make the equation true.

```
If all of the above have a computed value other than 'auto', the values are 
said to be "over-constrained" and one of the used values will have to be 
different from its computed value. If the 'direction' property of the 
containing block has the value 'ltr', the specified value of 'margin-right' 
is ignored and the value is calculated so as to make the equality true. If 
the value of 'direction' is 'rtl', this happens to 'margin-left' instead.
```

So, it h1 is block-level element, there is no way to remove the right-margin;

1. If you just want to center h1, you can set

   h1 {
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
   }

According to the equation above, the margin-left and margin-right will be calculated to same value, so h1 can be centered in this way;

2. If you want to position h1 anywhere, you can add margin-left or padding-left to arbitrary value to get your purpose;
3. Or, as you need, you can change h1 from block-level to inline-block, which will really move the right-margin:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello, title!</h1>
  <p>Hello, world!</p>
</body>
```